# Using Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll instead of System.Data.Services.Client.dll causes issues with Azure.StorageClient

Tags: wcf, azure, odata

We have a project that uses WCF 5.0 and the WindowsAzure SDK.

There are two references Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll and System.Data.Services.Client.dll and they are in conflict.  If I remove the System DLL (as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773011/microsoft-data-services-client-dll-vs-system-data-services-client-dll))  I am unable to use the windowsAzure SDK.  If I remove the Microsoft DLL I am unable to take advantage of the new features of WCF specifically OData version 3.0.

After I remove the System DLL reference:

> cannot convert from
>   'System.Data.Services.Client.SaveChangesOptions [c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft WCF Data
>   Services\5.0\bin.NETFramework\Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll]' to
>   'System.Data.Services.Client.SaveChangesOptions'

Additional information:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.TableServiceContext.SaveChangesWithRetries(System.Data.Services.Client.SaveChangesOptions)'
>   has some invalid arguments
>
> The type 'System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext' is defined
>   in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to
>   assembly 'System.Data.Services.Client, Version=3.5.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

If I remove the reference to Microsoft.Data.Services.Client and add reference to System.Data.Services.Client then we get no errors - we also get no WCF 5.0!

Comment: I've recently updated my references to WCF 5.0, but haven't found any issue. The only thing different from what you have done, is that I've replaced other references in my projects (like System.Data.Services to Microsoft.Data.Services). Your problem doesn't seem related to Azure.StorageClient, but to a namespace collision.

Comment: Somehow Azure.Storage.Client requires System.Data.Services.Client and not Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.  I will update my original post to display additional errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to repro this problem fairly quickly. The Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Dll has direct reference dependency on System.Data.Service.Client.Dll as shown below so if you are going to use Azure Storage Client API you would have to reference System.Data.Service.Client.Dll in your application and sure you can not use oData 3.0 supplied by WCF 5.0 SDK. More info is posted in the SO question below:

[WCF 5.0 and oData 3.0 API not work with azure table storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889274/wcf-5-0-and-odata-3-0-api-not-work-with-azure-table-storage/10889397#10889397)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **extern alias** to differentiate between two type names that are identical apart from the assembly in which they are contained.

1. Set an alias for System.Data.Services.Client - say SystemDataV4

   (See [MSDN Blogs - Extern Alais Walkthrough](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ansonh/archive/2006/09/27/774692.aspx))
2. At the very top of your .cs file use

   extern alias SystemDataV4;

Then you can either have

```
using SystemDataV4.System.Data.Services.Client;
```

or

```
serviceContext.SaveChangesWithRetries(SystemDataV4.System.Data.Services.Client.SaveChangesOptions.ReplaceOnUpdate);
```

Note the prefix of the namespace with the alias, e.g. **SystemDataV4**.System.Data.Services...