# WCF Data Services 5.0

Tags: c#, .net, wcf-data-services, appharbor

I recently updated to Visual Studio 2012 and now, when I create a new WCF Data Service in my MVC project, AppHarbor seems to be missing the assembly for Microsoft.Data.Services 5.0. Anyone was able to work around this problem? Or anyone knows if AppHarbor is planning on supporting WCF DS 5.0?

The problem is, whenever I add the assembly to my project, my project complains about conflicts between System.Data.Services and Microsoft.Data.Services. If I remove System.Data.Services, then my ODataContext class throws errors saying it can't find the IUpdatable interface.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to install [Data Services from NuGet](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.Services) and use [NuGet package restore](http://blog.appharbor.com/2012/02/06/use-nuget-package-restore-to-avoid-pushing-packages-to-appharbor) to have AppHarbor fetch the package?

You should probably resolve the conflict too - there are more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773011/microsoft-data-services-client-dll-vs-system-data-services-client-dll).